# How can I write a macro for batch "fit to drawing" operation in Visio?

Tags: vba, visio

I need to first save all visio files by applying "fit to drawing" option and then I want to save them as PDF files. But I am not really familiar with macros. Can somebody help me out?

My folder structure is like this:

- Folder with visio files

  - Visio file
  - Visio file
- Folder with visio files

  - Visio file

I need to have a pdf file for each visio files at the end and all diagrams should be fitted to drawing. I use Visio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code can help !

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim fso As Object, m_fld As Object, fld As Object, vd As Object, mf As String
Dim pdfn As String
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
mf = InputBox("Path")
Set m_fld = fso.getfolder(mf)
For Each fld In m_fld.subfolders
    For Each fil In fld.Files
    If InStr(fil.Name, ".vsd") > 0 Then fit (fil.Path) ' MsgBox fil.Name
    Next
Next
For Each fil In m_fld.Files
    If InStr(fil.Name, ".vsd") > 0 Then fit (fil.Path)
Next
End Sub
Sub fit(fn As String)
Dim fd As Document
Set fd = Documents.OpenEx(fn, visOpenRW)
pdfn = Replace(fd.FullName, Right(fd.FullName, Len(fd.FullName) - InStrRev(fd.FullName, ".")), "pdf")
For Each pg In fd.Pages
    fd.Application.ActiveWindow.Page = pg.Name
    Application.ActiveWindow.ViewFit = visFitPage
Next
fd.ExportAsFixedFormat visFixedFormatPDF, pdfn, visDocExIntentScreen, visPrintAll
fd.Save
fd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought it worked but it didnt even fit to drawing and it crashed at some point.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about export to pdf. I modified my code for do it

Comment: It saves as pdf now but it doesn't fit to drawing.